# move_group with 2DOF workpiece positioner and 6DOF robot

Tags: ros, moveit, robot, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am programming cell with 2DOF workpiece positioner and 6DOF robot in MoveIt! How many move_groups is better to do for synchro motions? One general move_group with 8 joints? Or may be two move_groups: 2DOF and 6DOF? Or may be move_group with two subgroups?
Something like that:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269763/move_group-with-2dof-workpiece-positioner-and-6dof-robot/) by [Vlad222](https://answers.ros.org/users/24466/vlad222/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you mean to ask about "planning groups". The term "move group" is quite overloaded within MoveIt! and `move_group` usually refers to the ROS node.

You probably want to have two separate planning groups to be able to plan with just one of the two joint sets.
To actuate the whole set together, just create another group with the two "basic" groups as subgroups.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1